# Definition of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis

I recently learned about convex functions and tried to come up with the definition on my own:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on some interval $I$ if for all $x_1\leq x_2$ with $x_1,x_2 \in I$ and $\forall x \in I$ we have

$\dfrac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}\cdot (x-x_1) + f(x_1) \geq f(x)$. The original definition is quite different so I wondered whether this one is also correct to some extent. The LHS is just the equation for the line joining the two points and the RHS the respective value the function attains.

The original definition I'm referring with the same initial assumptions looks like $f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda) f(x_2)$ for $\lambda \in [0,1].$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these two definitions are equivalent. You can show this by setting $x = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2$ or $\lambda = \frac{x_2 - x}{x_2-x_1}$.